# is there a basic abstract algebra text written with categorical views?

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

I see majority of mathematicians here are using language of category theory.

I have studied really basic chapters of abstract algebra texts, namely Dummit&Foote, Lang.

However, I saw a post that most definitions given in elementary abstract algebra texts are inconsistent with definitions in category theory.

I don't know anything about category theory, but I think that category theory is one of the final stages of mathematics one must reach.

Because of this reason, I want to know whether there is a basic abstract algebra text written with categorical views. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is Algebra Chapter 0 by Paolo Aluffi. It is designed to cover basic algebraic topics using category theory. [http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Chapter-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821847813](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847813) I would definitely recommend it based on my personal experience reading it. It doesn't even necessarily require previous algebra knowledge because it is partially written because the author believes using categories is a natural way to first learn about algebra (though this is defiinitely not a generally accepted belief).

Answer (score 1):

*Algebra* by Mac Lane and Birkoff will introduce you to categorical ideas in a painless way by the masters.